# Verizon MiFi Jetpack 6620L in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, 16.04, realtek-wireless

I have an Asus X200MA running Ubuntu 16.04. I also have a Verizon Jetpack MiFi 6620L. Now, the problem is that the MiFi wireless network does not work with ubuntu. Let me be more specific:

When i connect to the mifi network, no matter how close or far away the MiFi unit is, my connections manager shows that everything is as it should be. However, when I open up Firefox, Chromium, or any internet-requiring application, it loads for about 5 minutes then admits that it cannot find the server.

The only way to get the MiFi to work is plugging it into my computer's USB port and using USB tether mode. I already tried resetting the MiFi and that didn't work, so that is not the solution. The MiFi works excellent with *everything* else, like my old Windows 7 computer and even a Macbook Air I tried with it. (However, when I had Ubuntu 14.04 installed on this computer I had the same problem.) Please help! I really need to be able to use the network!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wireless connected but no internet access](http://askubuntu.com/questions/653355/wireless-connected-but-no-internet-access)

Comment: What is "MiFi"?

Comment: @Pilot6 :Mifi is a Verizon product. It's a small black and red box that creates a wifi hotspot and transmits data through 4g. Wifi is pretty much universal, so you know how surprised I was when it didn't work with Ubuntu.