# Wifi connected but no internet at certain (university) network ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless

After installing ubuntu 16.04 I can use wifi properly with my home router but get problem at university network. It shows that wifi is connected but actually no internet.

1.I have followed the following link but no internet.
[Wireless connected but no internet access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653355/wireless-connected-but-no-internet-access?newreg=fc6caecf4eee4ed984d428025d07e05e)

Result of the following commands are given below

```
ping 8.8.8.8
cat /etc/lsb-release; uname -a
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
iwconfig
rfkill list all
lsmod

2.ping 8.8.8.8
    result:ping 8.8.8.8 connect network is unreachable

3.cat /etc/lsb-release; uname -a
    result:DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
    Linux andypc 4.8.0-49-generic #52~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 10:55:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

4.lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
result:01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [17aa:3833]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0901]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
4.iwconfig
result:wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"WRS55"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: 98:DE:D0:E5:6B:64   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:87  Invalid misc:1326   Missed beacon:0

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

5.rfkill list all
result:0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

6.lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ccm                    20480  2
rfcomm                 77824  0
bnep                   20480  2
arc4                   16384  2
rtsx_usb_ms            20480  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_usb_ms
uvcvideo               90112  0
snd_soc_skl            65536  0
snd_soc_skl_ipc        45056  1 snd_soc_skl
intel_rapl             20480  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
snd_soc_sst_ipc        16384  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_sst_dsp        32768  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
snd_hda_ext_core       28672  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45056  1
snd_soc_sst_match      16384  1 snd_soc_skl
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_soc_core          233472  1 snd_soc_skl
videodev              180224  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
coretemp               16384  0
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
kvm                   598016  0
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           86016  7 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
ath10k_pci             45056  0
ath10k_core           335872  1 ath10k_pci
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
aesni_intel           167936  4
snd_pcm               110592  9 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_soc_core
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
ath                    32768  1 ath10k_core
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
hci_uart               98304  0
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btqca                  16384  1 hci_uart
btbcm                  16384  2 hci_uart,btusb
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
btintel                16384  2 hci_uart,btusb
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 ablk_helper,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
bluetooth             557056  33 btrtl,hci_uart,btintel,btqca,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
mac80211              761856  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              581632  3 mac80211,ath,ath10k_core
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
ideapad_laptop         24576  0
serio_raw              16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
ucsi                   16384  0
tpm_crb                16384  0
mei_me                 40960  0
snd                    86016  22 snd_compress,snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
shpchp                 36864  0
intel_lpss_acpi        16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mac_hid                16384  0
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_acpi
acpi_pad               24576  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
autofs4                40960  2
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         28672  0
rtsx_usb               24576  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
amdkfd                139264  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
radeon               1515520  1
i915                 1314816  105
psmouse               139264  0
ttm                   102400  1 radeon
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 radeon,i915
drm_kms_helper        167936  2 radeon,i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   368640  9 radeon,i915,ttm,drm_kms_helper
r8169                  81920  0
ahci                   36864  3
mii                    16384  1 r8169
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    16384  1 ideapad_laptop
pinctrl_sunrisepoint    28672  0
i2c_hid                20480  0
video                  40960  2 i915,ideapad_laptop
hid                   122880  1 i2c_hid
pinctrl_intel          20480  1 pinctrl_sunrisepoint
fjes                   28672  0
```

**my university guideline to connect wifi......https://www.urz.ovgu.de/urz/Unsere+Leistungen/Datennetz/Campus/WLAN/Anleitungen-p-1072.html

Comment: If you try connecting to a webpage, do you get redirected to a (captive) login portal?

Comment: no, I do not get redirected to a (captive) login portal