# Ubuntu 20.04 says that Wi-Fi is connected but doesn't allow me to connect to the internet

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, wifi-direct

I think this question has been asked multiple times all for different versions but I still have had no luck connecting to the internet.

When I connect to my router from Wifi settings it gives me a little connected icon on the top right corner but when I try to surf the internet I get the no internet dino.

I have tried using all the answers from these questions: [Wireless connected but no internet access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653355/wireless-connected-but-no-internet-access) and [Wireless network troubleshooter](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-initial-check.html.en) as well as some blog posts but no luck.

If I run `nmcli device` I get:

```
DEVICE          TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION
wlp1s0          wifi      connected     SpectrumSetup-90
virbr0          bridge    connected     virbr0
p2p-dev-wlp1s0  wifi-p2p  disconnected  --
lo              loopback  unmanaged     --
virbr0-nic      tun       unmanaged     --
```

When I try to ping googles IP I get:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.7 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2008ms
```

and when I run `ifconfig` I get:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6  ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txgueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 77276  bytes 11254278 (11.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 77276  bytes 11254278 (11.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:d3:76:87  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.253  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2605:e000:151f:867c::174b  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2605:e000:151f:867c:e9a7:64a4:4936:d44d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2605:e000:151f:867c:9c7f:1bcd:f035:752c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2605:e000:151f:867c:eb72:697:939a:2674  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2605:e000:151f:867c:11a1:8b65:118f:1148  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::5780:e027:f44:97  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fe80::67ed:55d1:ee99:7806  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2605:e000:151f:867c:f18e:c473:751f:31c7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2605:e000:151f:867c:720c:ec64:4404:a9c0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 70:1c:e7:76:ce:0b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2053  bytes 180506 (180.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8237  bytes 882378 (882.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here is the route output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination    Gateway      Genmask        Flags  Metric  Ref  Use  Iface
default        192.168.0.1  0.0.0.0        UG     302     0    0    wlp1s0
link-local     0.0.0.0      255.255.0.0    U      1000    0    0    virbr0
192.168.0.0    0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0  U      302     0    0    wlp1s0
192.168.1.0    0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0  U      600     0    0    wlp1s0
192.168.122.0  0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0  U      0       0    0    virbr0
```

If your are going to use any specific information from the outputs please comment on the question because I ran this on another computer and I had to copy it by hand.

Comment: post `route` command output.

Comment: @rtaft I just did

Comment: Can you verify the gateway is 192.168.0.1 when you copied that?  Your IP is not in that network.

Comment: Yeah, the gateway is 192.168.0.1

Comment: can you ping the gateway?

Comment: No, the error says: `ping: connect: Network is unreachable`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113657/discussion-between-fateh-aliyev-and-rtaft).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gateway 192.168.0.1 does not exist and the correct gateway is 192.168.1.1.  Since this is configured to use DHCP, the router is likely configured incorrectly and would need to be addressed there.

You could also manually set your IP address in the IPv4 tab of the settings for this connection.  Set the IP to a value between 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.99, the netmask to 255.255.255.0 and the gateway to 192.168.1.1.

Manually fixing the route would be
`route del default gw 192.168.0.1`
and `route add default gw 192.168.1.1`