# Ubuntu 22.04: Connected to wifi but browser says no internet

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, internet

sorry if a similar thing has already been asked before, but I already tried all solutions I could find online and none of them worked for me. So I thought maybe my case is unique and decided to start a thread.

I'm super new to Linux and I set up a dual-boot environment with Windows 10 only a few days ago. Everything worked perfectly fine at first, except the wifi kept fluctuating, but it worked all the same, and I was able to browse the web just fine. However, this morning when I opened Ubuntu I realized I can connect to the wifi but every time I try to open a site on my browser it will load for some time and then return "no internet" or "the site can't be reached". I already checked Windows and it doesn't have this problem. Everything's working smoothly on all my other devices too; I even restarted my router and all. So I figured the problem is with Ubuntu.

Here are the solutions I tried, all of which didn't fix it for me:

**1. Disabled 802.11n Protocol**

`sudo rmmod iwlwifi`

According to the article I was reading, I was supposed to run `sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` here, but couldn't go any further because the first command returned this:

`rmmod: ERROR: Module iwlwifi is not currently loaded`

**2. "Fixed" the glitch in Debian-Avahi daemon**

`sudo nano /etc/nsswitch/conf`

Looked for this certain line

`hosts:    files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] DNS mdns4`

In my case there wasn't "`mdns4`" after "`DNS`", but I removed it all the same and replaced the whole line with this:

`hosts:    files DNS`

Saved changes, restarted PC. No luck.

**3. Disabled IPv6 support**

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
```

**4. Disabled power management on adapter**

`lshw -C network`

Looked for logical name, it said: wlo1. So I went ahead and run `iwconfig wlo1 power off`, verified the changes and saw Power Management=off. No luck.

**5. Disabled WiFi power management**

`sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

Changed value from 3 to 2, saved changes, and restarted PC.

**6. Removed backport-iwlwifi-dkms package**

`sudo apt remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms`

But it returned this along with other lines:

`Package 'backport-iwlwifi-dkms' is not installed, so not removed`

And

`The following package was autoinstalled and is no longer required: libnss3-tools`

So I also sudo apt autoremove'd that

I also retraced my steps last night (since this problem only appeared this morning), and I didn't really do anything except install ProtonVPN, so I'm not sure where exactly it all went wrong. Any other ideas how to fix this? Thanks

BTW, this is my wireless info:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 04 Aug 2023 15:40 PST +0800

Booted last: 04 Aug 2023 00:00 PST +0800

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.19.0-50-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jul 10 18:24:29 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Xubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:3040]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 3151:1002 YICHIP Wireless Device
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5a11 IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0781:557d SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Force
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13d3:3529 IMC Networks Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

mac80211             1323008  2 rtw88_pci,rtw88_core
cfg80211             1052672  2 rtw88_core,mac80211
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
asus_wmi               57344  2 asus_nb_wmi,mfd_aaeon
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
platform_profile       16384  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    32768  3 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mfd_aaeon
video                  65536  2 asus_wmi,i915

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether (redacted) brd <MAC address>
    altname wlp2s0
    inet 192.168.1.4/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 86113sec preferred_lft 86113sec
4: ipv6leakintrf0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether (redacted) brd <MAC address>
    inet6 fdeb:446c:912d:8da::/64 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c365:343:84d5:af8d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

ipv6leakintrf0  no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"PLDTHOMEFIBR4dN8a"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: (redacted)   
          Bit Rate=108 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.4 metric 600 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         832       1  0 14:38 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtw_8821ce
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.19.0-50-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (redacted)
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/0000:02:00.0/net/wlo1
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:02:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlo1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     PLDTHOMEFIBR4dN8a
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       7e31e61a-363f-40ad-abd6-c5f8844b0f91
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/10
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     108 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               no
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.4/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        expiry = 1691220950
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.4
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1,/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/3,/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/4
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   7e31e61a-363f-40ad-abd6-c5f8844b0f91 | PLDTHOMEFIBR4dN8a
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   c7a6d3ea-2b2e-4f5a-95af-5997edcd48b3 | PLDTHOMEFIBR5Gbfv3F
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[3]:   521ece06-df99-446d-a808-7dd4898d7a6c | AN5506-04-FA_04528

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         ipv6leakintrf0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           dummy
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceDummy
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         dummy
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.19.0-50-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (redacted)
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/virtual/net/ipv6leakintrf0
GENERAL.PATH:                           --
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       ipv6leakintrf0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    yes
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     pvpn-ipv6leak-protection
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       07c8300e-fe76-4b37-81b4-2afe58be3c46
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/7
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               yes
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::c365:343:84d5:af8d/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         fdeb:446c:912d:8da::/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fdeb:446c:912d:8da::1
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fdeb:446c:912d:8da::/64, nh = ::, mt = 95
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fdeb:446c:912d:8da::1, mt = 95
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
IP6.DNS[1]:                             ::1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   07c8300e-fe76-4b37-81b4-2afe58be3c46 | pvpn-ipv6leak-protection

SSID                   BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  IN-USE 
PLDTHOMEFIBR5Gbfv3F    (redacted)  Infra  149   5745 MHz  270 Mbit/s  82      ▂▄▆█  WPA2       no             
PLDTHOMEFIBR4dN8a     (redacted)  Infra  11    2462 MHz  270 Mbit/s  78      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       yes     *      
AN5506-04-FA_04528     (redacted)  Infra  1     2412 MHz  270 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no             
PLDTHOMEFIBR5GzqUN3    (redacted)  Infra  149   5745 MHz  270 Mbit/s  25      ▂___  WPA2       no             
AN5506-04-FA_04528_5G  (redacted)  Infra  36    5180 MHz  270 Mbit/s  17      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no             

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/PLDTHOMEFIBR4dN8a.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=PLDTHOMEFIBR4dN8a | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=PLDTHOMEFIBR4dN8a
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=disabled

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/PLDTHOMEFIBR5Gbfv3F.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=PLDTHOMEFIBR5Gbfv3F | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=PLDTHOMEFIBR5Gbfv3F
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AN5506-04-FA_04528.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=AN5506-04-FA_04528 | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=AN5506-04-FA_04528
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

ipv6leakintrf0  no frequency information.

wlo1      32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlo1      Interface doesn't support scanning : Device or resource busy

ipv6leakintrf0  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.19.0-50-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-50-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.19.0-50-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[ 3189.227118] wlo1: RX AssocResp from (redacted) (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=21)
[ 3189.227425] wlo1: associated
[ 3189.317768] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 16 (16 - 0) dBm as advertised by (redacted)
[ 3229.488590] wlo1: authenticate with (redacted)
[ 3229.488627] wlo1: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[ 3230.134957] wlo1: send auth to (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3230.136444] wlo1: authenticated
[ 3230.138946] wlo1: associate with (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3230.142910] wlo1: RX AssocResp from (redacted) (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=21)
[ 3230.143105] wlo1: associated
[ 3230.182524] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 16 (16 - 0) dBm as advertised by (redacted)
[ 3241.585272] wlo1: authenticate with (redacted)
[ 3241.585317] wlo1: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[ 3242.230846] wlo1: send auth to (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3242.232321] wlo1: authenticated
[ 3242.234822] wlo1: associate with (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3242.238848] wlo1: RX AssocResp from (redacted) (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=21)
[ 3242.239128] wlo1: associated
[ 3242.270398] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 16 (16 - 0) dBm as advertised by (redacted)
[ 3257.572606] wlo1: authenticate with (redacted)
[ 3257.572640] wlo1: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[ 3258.222381] wlo1: send auth to (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3258.223827] wlo1: authenticated
[ 3258.226380] wlo1: associate with (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3258.230884] wlo1: RX AssocResp from (redacted) (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=21)
[ 3258.231220] wlo1: associated
[ 3258.335280] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 16 (16 - 0) dBm as advertised by (redacted)
[ 3275.560615] wlo1: authenticate with (redacted)
[ 3275.560651] wlo1: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[ 3276.206859] wlo1: send auth to (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3276.208390] wlo1: authenticated
[ 3276.210671] wlo1: associate with (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3276.214667] wlo1: RX AssocResp from (redacted) (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=21)
[ 3276.214873] wlo1: associated
[ 3276.274488] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 16 (16 - 0) dBm as advertised by (redacted)
[ 3306.576611] wlo1: authenticate with (redacted)
[ 3306.576649] wlo1: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[ 3307.226559] wlo1: send auth to (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3307.228053] wlo1: authenticated
[ 3307.230319] wlo1: associate with (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3307.235975] wlo1: RX AssocResp from (redacted) (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=21)
[ 3307.236169] wlo1: associated
[ 3307.298951] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 16 (16 - 0) dBm as advertised by (redacted)
[ 3318.576874] wlo1: authenticate with (redacted)
[ 3318.576918] wlo1: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[ 3319.222850] wlo1: send auth to (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3319.224347] wlo1: authenticated
[ 3319.226300] wlo1: associate with (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3319.230273] wlo1: RX AssocResp from (redacted)  (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=21)
[ 3319.230463] wlo1: associated
[ 3319.263607] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 16 (16 - 0) dBm as advertised by (redacted)
[ 3341.549240] wlo1: authenticate with (redacted)
[ 3341.549283] wlo1: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[ 3342.194411] wlo1: send auth to (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3342.195897] wlo1: authenticated
[ 3342.198568] wlo1: associate with (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3342.205004] wlo1: RX AssocResp from (redacted) (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=21)
[ 3342.205209] wlo1: associated
[ 3342.304182] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 16 (16 - 0) dBm as advertised by (redacted)
[ 3370.520949] wlo1: authenticate with (redacted)
[ 3370.520992] wlo1: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[ 3371.166923] wlo1: send auth to (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3371.168407] wlo1: authenticated
[ 3371.170400] wlo1: associate with (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3371.174332] wlo1: RX AssocResp from (redacted) (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=21)
[ 3371.174529] wlo1: associated
[ 3371.180736] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 16 (16 - 0) dBm as advertised by (redacted)
[ 3413.616685] wlo1: authenticate with (redacted)
[ 3413.616723] wlo1: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[ 3414.262821] wlo1: send auth to (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3414.264449] wlo1: authenticated
[ 3414.266656] wlo1: associate with (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3414.270629] wlo1: RX AssocResp from (redacted) (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=21)
[ 3414.270832] wlo1: associated
[ 3414.314394] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 16 (16 - 0) dBm as advertised by (redacted)
[ 3460.070587] wlo1: deauthenticating from (redacted) by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 3469.075874] wlo1: authenticate with (redacted)
[ 3469.075908] wlo1: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[ 3469.722409] wlo1: send auth to (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3469.725237] wlo1: authenticated
[ 3469.726806] wlo1: associate with (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3469.730792] wlo1: RX AssocResp from (redacted) (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=21)
[ 3469.731079] wlo1: associated
[ 3469.792601] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 16 (16 - 0) dBm as advertised by (redacted)
[ 3709.556719] wlo1: authenticate with (redacted)
[ 3709.556756] wlo1: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[ 3710.202865] wlo1: send auth to (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3710.204595] wlo1: authenticated
[ 3710.206553] wlo1: associate with (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3710.210534] wlo1: RX AssocResp from (redacted) (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=21)
[ 3710.210826] wlo1: associated
[ 3710.246451] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 16 (16 - 0) dBm as advertised by (redacted)
[ 3735.592966] wlo1: authenticate with (redacted)
[ 3735.593008] wlo1: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[ 3736.238837] wlo1: send auth to (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3736.240347] wlo1: authenticated
[ 3736.242543] wlo1: associate with (redacted) (try 1/3)
[ 3736.246516] wlo1: RX AssocResp from (redacted) (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=21)
[ 3736.246711] wlo1: associated
[ 3736.341498] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 16 (16 - 0) dBm as advertised by (redacted)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Please see your interface includes ipv6leakintrf0. Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372873/connected-on-wireless-but-no-internet-access-in-ubuntu-20-04  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Blindly applying system changes prior to diagnosing the problem is a Well-Known Path to Disaster, and, probably doesn't solve the problem. Diagnose, then fix.