# DNS_Probe_Possible

Tags: networking, dns, ethernet

I'm having an issue where I'm unable to connect to the internet

Whenever I open any browser, I get the error "DNS_Probe_Possible"

**Here's my basic system info:**

```
Distro - Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Type - 64-bit
GNOME - 42.9
```

**Here's the steps I've taken to try and resolve the issue already:**

1. I'd set my DNS to 1.1.1.1 - so I changed it to another DNS tested
   that and also Automatic
2. I tried flushing the DNS with "sudo resolvectl flush-caches"
3. I use a powerline adapter, so I've tried unplugging this and such (My other devices connected to this end of the adapter work fine)
4. I tried unplugging the ethernet cable and leaving it for a while
5. Restarting - shutdown - hard reset
6. Google suggested it could be firewall - disabling UFW doesn't change anything
7. I tried multiple ethernet cables and setups and they all get the same results

**Other notes:**

I remote into the machine, so it's connecting to my LAN at least. Just seems to be the connection outside of my network it doesn't like

This machine is quite old frankly and before when it was running Windows 10, it had a consistent issue of saying "No internet" but allowing me to RDP in. But unplugging the ethernet for a second usually fixed it. So my personal assessment is that it's likely a driver issue with the ethernet

Problem is without the ability to communicate to the internet, I'm really unsure where to go from here

**Edit:**

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=26.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=15.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=60 time=15.6 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.587/19.090/26.097/4.954 ms

ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
ping: www.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

^ Tried that twice as well to the same result

```
resolvectl status
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp1s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (ipv6leakintrf0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: ::1
       DNS Servers: ::1
        DNS Domain: ~.
```

I'm setting the DNS in the settings of Ubuntu through the GUI

[Error Message Within Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BGDy.png)

It is not site specific, I've tried youtube.com & google.com

Also tried the plex server which is hosted from this machine and get the below:

[Plex Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYVE5.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and: `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com`

Comment: Edited everything, thanks for pitching in!

Comment: How does it get its IP address? Is it connected to a router that serves as a DHCP server? Or does it have a static IP address? Or anything else? How do your other devices get their DNS server?

Comment: It's got a static IP. That is something which I thought might be worth trying to change, but I also didn't want to straight away

The only other PC uses a static IP also, all other devices use DHCP

Comment: Next, let's see: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Was there a VPN here previously? Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372873/connected-on-wireless-but-no-internet-access-in-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 2):

chili 555 Legend thank you that!

`pvpn-ipv6leak-protection` - protonVPN left this on more than likely after I tinkered with their kill switch option

Really strange it didn't remove this after I turned it back off

running `nmcli connection delete pvpn-ipv6leak-protection` resolved the issue